# Razor behaving differently on server vs locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an odd problem with MVC Razor @ escaping.

In some javascript in my view I have a line like this. The aim is to see if e is an email address containing a . before the @:

```
if (e.indexOf(".") < e.indexOf("@@")) { //Assume use firstname.lastname@... }
```

When testing locally, it renders correctly as:

```
if (e.indexOf(".") < e.indexOf("@")) { //Assume use firstname.lastname@... }
```

However on the server it renders as:

```
if (e.indexOf(".") < e.indexOf("@@")) { //Assume use firstname.lastname@... }
```

Which of course means it doesn't work.

I deploy to the server via SVN, so all the files are identical apart from web.config.

What could be causing this? I'm using MVC 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried @:@@ to output '@' as text?

Comment: Yes, I get Parser Error:  ":" is not valid at the start of a code block.

Comment: Code produced: if (e.indexOf(".") < e.indexOf("@:@@")) {

Comment: Haven't tried server side but indexOf("@("@")") works locally

Comment: That again comes out verbatim. In the end I got it working by creating a variable: var atSign = '@@'; and then using this in my IF statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sidestep the @ confusion if you use `\x40` instead.

```
if (e.indexOf(".") < e.indexOf("\x40")) { ... }
```